# Excel - I want to list all account numbers associated with an email

Tags: microsoft-excel

First post - sorry if it is lacking any information that it shouldn't be.

I have a master set of data from my customer portfolio that looks like this (for example):

```
╔═══════════════╦═════════════════════╗
║ AccountNumber ║        Email        ║
╠═══════════════╬═════════════════════╣
║ AC0001        ║ example_1@email.com ║
║ AC0002        ║ example_1@email.com ║
║ AC0003        ║ example_2@email.com ║
║ AC0004        ║ example_3@email.com ║
║ AC0005        ║ example_3@email.com ║
╚═══════════════╩═════════════════════╝
```

I want to format the data so that each row is for each unique email address, and then I want to add a column in for each account associated with that email. Like this:

```
╔═════════════════════╦══════════╦══════════╗
║        Email        ║ Account1 ║ Account2 ║
╠═════════════════════╬══════════╬══════════╣
║ example_1@email.com ║ AC0001   ║ AC0002   ║
║ example_2@email.com ║ AC0003   ║          ║
║ example_3@email.com ║ AC0004   ║ AC0005   ║
╚═════════════════════╩══════════╩══════════╝
```

I've tried to pivot this but it's not quite right, so hoping the community will help me out.

Thanks,
Harrison

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

**How it works:**

- An array (CSE) formula in cell `U34`:

  ```
  {=IFERROR(INDEX(V$27:V$31,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($U$33:U33,V$27:V$31),0)),"")}
  ```
- Array (CSE) Formula in cell `V34`:

  ```
  {=IFERROR(INDEX($U27:$U31,SMALL(IF($V27:$V31=$U34,ROW($U27:$U31)-MIN(ROW($U27:$U31))+1),COLUMNS($U$34:U34))),"")}
  ```

**N.B.**

- Finish both formula with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** then fill down & across.
- Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.

Comment: Glad to help you @Harrison Clark,,, keep asking ☺